# Traverse a tree updating parent nodes with information obtained from the childs

Tags: java, tree

I have a JTree formed by DefaultMutableTreeNodes. Each node has a UserObject that contains some data. One of this data is a thing that I call "size". I would like to traveste the tree updating each node with the sum of the "sizes" of its children.

```
 public void traverse(DefaultMutableTreeNode root)
    {
        Field f;

        int offset = 0;
        int size = 0;

        // Just changing enumeration kind here
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en = root.postorderEnumeration();
        while (en.hasMoreElements())
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = en.nextElement();
            f = (Field)node.getUserObject();
            if (node.isLeaf())
            {
                size += f.getSize();
            }
            else
            {
                f.setSize(size);
                size = 0;
            }
            System.out.println((node.isLeaf() ? "  - " : "+ ") + " -----> "+f);
        }
    }
```

I've tried the code above, but it works only for nodes until the 2nd level.

What am I missing?

TIA.

Comment: What do you mean "sum of the sizes of its children"?  Do you mean the parent will have the sum of the sizes of only its direct children, or the sum of sizes from each subtree with its children as the roots?

Comment: Good point. Each "parent" has the sum of the sizes of your direct children. I suppose I would need some type of recursion here, but I couldn't made a functional code yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try:

Seudocode

```
    public void traverse(DefaultMutableTreeNode root)
{
    Field f;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Enumeration en = root.postorderEnumeration();
    while (en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) en.nextElement();
        if (currentNode.getParent() != null)
        {
            f = ((Field) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentNode.getParent()).getUserObject());
            f.setSize(f.getSize() + ((Field) ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) currentNode).getUserObject()).getSize());
        }
    }
}
```

This should work if `postOrderEnumerator` works the way I think it does.

Comment: Works like a charm. I've just to correct some syntax errors and adapt to use my UserObject on all nodes. Thanks a lot for your help.